# ASGI Django Application Hosting in Windows Server 2012

Tags: django, websocket, hosting, windows-server-2012, channel

Can I host ASGI Django App in Windows Server 2012 backed with Apache? I explored several blogs which mentions about "mod_wsgi" which confused me if it could handle ASGI application.

Can this server handle websocket requests?

[Medium/Analytics-Vidya](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/steps-to-deploy-python-django-application-on-windows-server-c6159aaff8ce)

[Prof. Dr. Christian Leubner](https://obelix.fh-swf.de/wp/deploying-django-on-windows-server-2019-and-apache-with-mod_wsgi/)

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'broadcast',
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'AppMain.asgi.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)],
            # "hosts":[os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')]
        },
    },
}
```

**asgi.py**

```
import os

import django
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from django.urls import path
from broadcast.consumers import AConsumer
import broadcast.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'AppMain.settings')
django.setup()

# application = get_asgi_application()
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http' : get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket' : AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            broadcast.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    )
})
```

Comment: Windows server 2012 is a decade old.  Shouldn't you be using a more recent server?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I mark your suggestions. Though its decade older, I have access only to locally configured Wndows server 2012 as of now. Can you help me choose correct server for hosting Django ASGI application? "I am in testing phase so I prefer free ones and when I go into production phase, I could upgrade into premium"